# Understanding construction of recursive data structures in C

Tags: c

Using C, I am basically wanting to create an abstract data type that represents a summary of a file system.  Each directory is a node in a tree that contains information about the files in that directory and a linked list of pointers to each subdirectory:

```
struct node:
    int file count
    struct node* head (pointer to "first next" of linked list of subdirectories)
    struct node* next
```

Early in my process I had decided to try for an iterative approach where a function would take a directory as input and return a linked list "to do list" of subdirectories to continue running through the function.  <strike>However, I discovered in this process that my malloced linked list was not valid memory after function return.</strike>

Truly I didn't mind a recursive approach since this tool would only be used on home systems and the recursion depth will not be great.  But it got me to thinking - how do I create a tree in memory with recursive functions <strike>if I am going to lose malloced pointers at each function return?</strike>

I have a drawing of the structure and wrote "use python instead" at the bottom of the paper - however I would like to understand what is common practice for creating these sorts of data structures in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstring>

#define SLASH '\\' // WINDOWS SLASH

/*Classification is determined by analyzing what a folder contains.  At the bottom there are Tracks
that are defined as audio files.  A folder that contains one or more audio files and no subdirectories
is classified as an Album.  A folder that contains one or more Albums is classified as a Collection.
A folder that contains one or more Collections is classified as a Library.  The Folder classification 
is reserved for folders that do not meet these classifications yet still contains Tracks.*/
enum classification{Folder, Library, Collection, Album, Track};

static int one(const struct dirent* unused)
{
    return 1;
}

struct Queue_Node {
    char* name;
    struct Queue_Node* next;
};

struct Chain_Node {
    struct Queue_Node* subdir_list;
    struct Chain_Node* next;
};

struct Dir_Tree_Node {
    char* name;
    enum classification type;
    struct Dir_Tree_Node* subdirs;
    struct Dir_Tree_Node* next; //linked list of subdirectories
    int audio_file_count; //current directory only
    int other_file_count; //current directory only, not including folders
};

struct Cur_Dir_Info {
    char* parent_path;
    struct Queue_Node* subdir;
    int audio_file_count;
    int other_file_count;
    struct Dir_Tree_Node* cursor;
};

struct Cur_Dir_Info list_and_count(char* current_directory, struct Dir_Tree_Node* cursor, struct Cur_Dir_Info* output) {

    //directory listing stuff
    struct dirent** eps;
    int n;
    n = scandir(current_directory, &eps, one, alphasort);
    size_t path_length = strlen(current_directory);
    struct stat* current_stat;
    current_stat = (struct stat*) malloc(sizeof(struct stat));

    //linked list queuing
    struct Queue_Node* first = NULL;
    first = (struct Queue_Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Queue_Node));
    if (!first) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: firstt (Queue_Node) allocation failed, exiting.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    struct Queue_Node* current = first;

    if (n >= 0) {
        for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) { //scandir will index "." and ".." at 0 & 1, start at 2
            //to-do parse out . & ..
            char fullname[1000] = { NULL };
            int j = 0;
            while (j < path_length) {
                fullname[j] = current_directory[j];
                j++;
            }
            int l = 0;
            if (fullname[path_length] != SLASH) {
                fullname[path_length] = SLASH;
                l = 1;
            }

            char shortname[261]; //need to dynamically allocate this in the future
            if (!shortname) {
                fprintf(stderr, "error: shortname (char*) allocation failed, exiting.\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            memcpy(shortname, eps[i]->d_name, sizeof(eps[i]->d_name));

            for (unsigned int k = 0; k < strlen(eps[i]->d_name) / sizeof(char); k++) {
                fullname[path_length + k + l] = shortname[k * sizeof(char)];
            }

            stat(fullname, current_stat);
            if (current_stat != NULL && S_ISDIR(current_stat->st_mode) != 0) {
                //printf("Found directory: %s\n", fullname);
                // TO DO: . and .. are not valid directory names

                current->name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(fullname));
                if (!current->name) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "error: current->name (char*) allocation failed, exiting.\n");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                memcpy(current->name, fullname, sizeof(fullname));

                struct Queue_Node* next = NULL;
                next = (struct Queue_Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Queue_Node));
                if (!next) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "error: next (Queue_Node) allocation failed, exiting.\n");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                current->next = next;
                current = next;
            }
        //TO DO: else { if (file is audio file) {count audio files} else {count other files}
        }           
    }
    else {
        perror("Couldn't open the directory");
    }
    output->subdir = first;
    return *output;
}
```

EDIT: malloced memory is valid on function return so my original recursive implementation worked fine once I debugged it.  I am learning a lot and my code looks really stinky in places I would appreciate suggestions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstring>

#define SLASH '\\' // WINDOWS SLASH

//Classification is determined by analyzing what a folder contains.  At the bottom there are Tracks
//that are defined as audio files.  A folder that contains one or more audio files and no subdirectories
//is classified as an Album.  A folder that contains one or more Albums is classified as a Collection.
//A folder that contains one or more Collections is classified as a Library.  The Folder classification 
//is reserved for folders that do not meet these classifications yet still contains Tracks.
enum classification { Folder, Library, Collection, Album, Track };

//selector function for scandir (3rd argument)
static int one(const struct dirent* unused)
{
    return 1;
}

struct Queue_Node {
    char* name;
    struct Queue_Node* next;
};

struct Chain_Node {
    struct Queue_Node* subdir_list;
    struct Chain_Node* next;
};

struct Dir_Tree_Node {
    char* name;
    enum classification type;
    struct Dir_Tree_Node* parent;
    struct Dir_Tree_Node* subdirs;
    struct Dir_Tree_Node* next; //linked list of subdirectories
    int audio_file_count; //current directory only
    int other_file_count; //current directory only, not including folders
};

struct Cur_Dir_Info {
    char* parent_path;
    struct Queue_Node* subdir;
    int audio_file_count;
    int other_file_count;
    struct Dir_Tree_Node* cursor;
};

struct Cur_Dir_Info* list_and_count(char* current_directory, struct Cur_Dir_Info* output) {

    //directory listing stuff
    struct dirent** eps;
    int n;
    n = scandir(current_directory, &eps, one, alphasort);
    //printf("Files in path: %d\n", n);
    size_t path_length = strlen(current_directory);
    //printf("Length of pathname: %zd\n", path_length);
    struct stat* current_stat;
    current_stat = (struct stat*) malloc(sizeof(struct stat));

    //linked list queuing
    struct Queue_Node* first = (struct Queue_Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Queue_Node));
    if (!first) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: first (Queue_Node) allocation failed, exiting.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    struct Queue_Node* current = first;

    int count = 0;
    if (n >= 3) {
        for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) { //scandir will index "." and ".." at 0 & 1, start at 2
            char fullname[1000] = { NULL };
            int j = 0;
            while (j < path_length) {
                fullname[j] = current_directory[j];
                j++;
            }
            int l = 0;
            if (fullname[path_length] != SLASH) {
                fullname[path_length] = SLASH;
                l = 1;
            }

            char shortname[261]; //need to dynamically allocate this in the future
            if (!shortname) {
                fprintf(stderr, "error: shortname (char*) allocation failed, exiting.\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            memcpy(shortname, eps[i]->d_name, sizeof(eps[i]->d_name));

            for (unsigned int k = 0; k < strlen(eps[i]->d_name) / sizeof(char); k++) {
                fullname[path_length + k + l] = shortname[k * sizeof(char)];
            }

            stat(fullname, current_stat);

            if (current_stat != NULL && S_ISDIR(current_stat->st_mode) != 0) {
                //printf("Found directory: %s\n", fullname);
                count++;
                // TO DO: . and .. are not valid directory names

                current->name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(fullname));
                if (!current->name) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "error: current->name (char*) allocation failed, exiting.\n");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                memcpy(current->name, fullname, sizeof(fullname));

                struct Queue_Node* next = (struct Queue_Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Queue_Node));
                if (!next) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "error: next (Queue_Node) allocation failed, exiting.\n");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                current->next = next;
                current = next;
            }
            current->name = nullptr;
            current->next = nullptr;
            //TO DO: else { if (file is audio file) {count audio files} else {count other files}
        }
        current = nullptr;
        //printf("Completed\n");
    }
    else {
        perror("Couldn't open the directory");
        first = nullptr;
    }

    output->parent_path = current_directory;
    if (count > 0) {
        output->subdir = first;
    }
    else {
        output->subdir = nullptr;
    }
    output->audio_file_count = 1;
    output->other_file_count = 2;
    return output;
}

void explore_paths(struct Dir_Tree_Node* current_path, struct Dir_Tree_Node* tree_cursor) {

    if (!current_path->name) {
        return;
    }

    char* current_directory = current_path->name;

    struct Queue_Node* current_subdirs = (struct Queue_Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Queue_Node));
    current_subdirs->name = current_directory;
    current_subdirs->next = nullptr;

    struct Cur_Dir_Info* output = (struct Cur_Dir_Info*)malloc(sizeof(struct Cur_Dir_Info));
    if (!output) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: output (Cur_Dir_Info) allocation failed, exiting.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    struct Queue_Node* cursor = current_subdirs; //initialize to root of path

    //printf("Running:  %s\n", current_directory);
    tree_cursor->name = current_directory;

    output = list_and_count(current_directory, output);

    struct Dir_Tree_Node* head = (struct Dir_Tree_Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Dir_Tree_Node));
    if (!head) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: next (Queue_Node) allocation failed, exiting.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (output->subdir) { //check if there are subdirectories
        struct Queue_Node* list = output->subdir;

        tree_cursor->subdirs = head;

        struct Dir_Tree_Node* current = (struct Dir_Tree_Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Dir_Tree_Node));
        if (!current) {
            fprintf(stderr, "error: next (Queue_Node) allocation failed, exiting.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        current = head;

        current->next = (struct Dir_Tree_Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Dir_Tree_Node));
        current->next->name = list->name;
        current = current->next;
        list = list->next;

        while (list) {
            current->next = (struct Dir_Tree_Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Dir_Tree_Node));
            current->next->name = list->name;
            current->parent = current_path;

            list = list->next;
            current = current->next;
            current->next = nullptr;
        }
        current = head->next;
        while (current->next) { //won't work if there is a single subdirectory
            printf("Checking Dir_Tree_Nodes %s\n", current->name);
            current = current->next;
        }
        //printf("finished Dir_Tree_Node write\n");
        head = head->next;
        explore_paths(head, head); //recurse downward
        current = nullptr;
    }
    //printf("Success and recursing\n");
    if (current_path->next) {
        current_path = current_path->next;
    }
    else {
        return;
    }
    //current_path->next = (struct Dir_Tree_Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Dir_Tree_Node));
    explore_paths(current_path, current_path);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Usage: One or more root paths to search from <path> <path> <path> ...");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("\nSearching ");
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        printf(argv[i]);
    } printf("\n\n");

    char** path_list = argv;
    char* current_directory = path_list[1];

    struct Dir_Tree_Node* root = (struct Dir_Tree_Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Dir_Tree_Node));
    root->name = current_directory;
    root->next = nullptr;
    struct Dir_Tree_Node* tree_cursor = root;

    explore_paths(root, tree_cursor);

    /*cursor = first;
    while (cursor != NULL) {
        struct Queue_Node* next = cursor->next;
        free(cursor);
        cursor = next;
    }*/
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "if I am going to lose malloced pointers at each function return" - you shouldn't be "losing" pointers to allocated data after the function returns, each node is a valid chunk of allocated memory which points to another valid chunk of allocated memory or NULL. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: OK!  I think I need to go back to that version of the code then - I reread the *cough* wikipedia article that I got this notion from and it adds the caveat that dynamically allocated memory remains valid on function return: "When returning a pointer from a function, do not return a pointer that points to a value that is local to the function or that is a pointer to a function argument. Pointers to local variables become invalid when the function exits. In the above function, the value returned points to a static variable. Returning a pointer to dynamically allocated memory is also valid."

Comment: added my embarrassing code

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I think the question is answered - due to a misunderstanding, I thought that I was getting bad pointers because "I was losing pointers at each function return" but now I think it was because I had a bug in my linked list allocation.